# Daily countdown to specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a daily countdown, eg lets say each day up to 7pm. Once 7pm is passed, it should start again at 23:59:59 and count down again to next day 7pm.

I wrote a script but nothing shows up. Why is the countdown not displaying?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 18-now.getHours();
  var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
      timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

var countdown;
function StopTime() {
    clearInterval(countdown);
    setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
setInterval('ShowTime()',1000);
```

to this

```
setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/1/)

Comment: Yes, updated this and the wrong variable naming: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/2/ but it is still not showing for me

Comment: i modified some updates in your code please go through the fiddle first and tell me ur problem

Comment: you put showTime in stopTime function so i updated out of the stop function

Comment: Or just call StopTime() it will run

Comment: OK, I see, that seems to work fine! Thanks. But now I discovered a new bug, that once the time is passed, it will not countdown toward the next time but rather show the time that is passed from the last countdown (eg "-2 hours 20 minutes 21 seconds" in stead of "22hours 39 minutes 39 seconds").

Comment: Sorry I am not expect in time function arise another question be useful for you.beacuse anyother can clarify your doubt

Answer (score 1):

Here you set the html of the div tag:

```
$("#countdown").html(str);
```

But what is `str`? Also, what is `timeleft`? Maybe you mean to say:

```
var timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
$("#countdown").html(timeLeft );
```

Comment: Yes indeed, didn't save the fiddle, now it is correct (also the setInterval fixed), but still nothing is showing: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/2/

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, it's for three reasons;

1) You never call ShowTime

2) Instead of `$("#countdown").html(str);` you should have `$("#countdown").html(timeLeft);`

3) Your setInterval should be `setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);`

Comment: Yes, I didn't save the jsfiddle (wanted to make it more clear) before posting. Update the code and fiddle, but still not displaying: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/2/

Comment: Your code works as it should, if you add something to start it - http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/4/